# Qt 5.1.1 compile errors in vs2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I'm working on upgrading a rather large project to Qt 5.1.1 from Qt 4.8.3.  We use vs2010 and I'm using the v1.2.2 VS Qt add-in.  I've fixed all the path issues that came with the addition of QtWidgets and some errors from the new implementation QPointer, but now am running across a specific set of errors that I'm hoping someone else has seen and been able to overcome:

```
1>c:\qt\qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2010_opengl\include\qtcore\qarraydataops.h(399): error C2171: '!' : illegal on operands of type ''unknown-type''
1>c:\qt\qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2010_opengl\include\qtcore\qarraydataops.h(400): error C2171: '!' : illegal on operands of type ''unknown-type''
1>c:\qt\qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2010_opengl\include\qtcore\qarraydataops.h(409): error C2171: '!' : illegal on operands of type ''unknown-type''
```

Has anyone seen this and found the root of the problem?

We are using boost 1.53 and Precompiled Headers, I have a hunch one of those might be a problem, as it looks like the problem arises when QtCore is included in a precompiled header.

Cheers

Comment: A coworker hit the same problem, while trying to run the static analysis on it (VS2012, Qt 5.0.2, 64-bit Windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too have seen this problem.  I was able to make it go away by disabling Visual Studio's code analysis on the project in question.